# Implementing external merge sort in linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list, mergesort

```
MergeSort(string fileName, int left, int right)
{
    int opCounter = 0;
    opCounter++;
    if (left < right)
    {
        opCounter++;
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        opCounter++;
        opCounter += MergeSort(fileName, left, mid);
        opCounter++;
        opCounter += MergeSort(fileName, mid + 1, right);
        opCounter++;
        opCounter += Merge(fileName, left, mid, right);
        opCounter++;
    }
    return opCounter;
}
```

How to perform this method with linked list? What should be "next", "previous" and "current"?

Comment: External merge sorts are done by sorting blocks of data that fit in memory (any stable sort will work), followed by a bottom up merge (breadth first) of the blocks of data until a single sorted block is produced. The blocks of data will need to kept track of (such as the start (and maybe the end) of each block), and a linked list could be used for this purpose.